# Passing a local variable into another view's JS - Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to grab / fetch a variable inside `js` between two different views? Say I have an index view with does:

```
<% foo.each do |foo| %>
  <%= link_to 'bar', bar_path %> 
<% end %>
```

Then in `bar` I want to add some jQuery to a specific element with `foo.id` selector:

```
$('div#<%= foo.id %>').fadeOut(); // I know the interpolation wouldn't work here
```

I know I can pass `foo.id` to `bar` with my path or send it via the `locals` hash, but how would I "grab" it with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily pass variables to JS using a gem called [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon).

```
gem "gon"
```

All you have to do is add this gem to you Gemfile and then you can call gon inside any controller like this:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    ...
    gon.controller = "payments"
    gon.action    = "new"
    gon.message   = "Hello World!"
    ...
  end 
end
```

And now, at any javascript (in following case, coffeescript) you can:

```
$ ->

  # Check if it is the target controller and action
  if gon? && gon.controller is "payments" &&  gon.action is "new"
    alert gon.message
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to grab / fetch a variable inside js between two
>   different views

Not without hacking.

JS is an client-side technology, meaning it loads in the browser, not on the server. This is famous for causing so many issues for developers trying to bind to dynamically-named objects, much like what you're trying to do.

There are several ways around this. I'll go through them for you:

---

**Class**

The first way is to use a broader identifier, such as `element` type or `class`.

You're currently trying to select `foo.id`, which means you're going to have to pass that data directly to JS somehow. Inefficient.

A much better way would be to use something like this:

```
$("a.bar").on("click", function(e){
   $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

--

**URL**

According to this resource, there are no inbuilt ways to pull query strings from JS: [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)

You *may* be able to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   foo = window.location.search.substring(1); //Considering you have http://url.com/your/foo/id
   $("#" + foo).fadeOut();
});
```

--

**ERB**

There is a final alternative, although this only works if you don't precompile your JS (which I'm not sure is actually feasible any more). That is to use `ERB` directly in your JS, rather like what you've done in the question.

Whilst this works for dynamic references (such as paths), I don't think it can pull data from a controller. Unless, of course, you put the script *directly* in your view - which goes against the conventions of MVC.

```
#app/views/bar/show.html.erb
<script>
   // your code here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a `js.erb` file and in that pass a variable defined in your controller action.
The code insde `js.erb` would look like this :

```
<% fields_html = render "fields", :entity => @model %>
$("#fields-list").html("<%= escape_javascript fields_html %>")
```

Here `fields` is a partial I have created. `:entity` is basically passing of the variable value. `@model` is the variable defined inside controller action. `fields-list` is the id of the field I want to load using `jquery`.